# How to find input type based on it's name Javascript/Mootools

Tags: javascript, forms, mootools

I have a form that submits values to database via Ajax and works fine but I also need to give option to user to reset the form to its default values in case they make a mistake.

The default values are stored in a javascript variable as json object

```
{"field_name1":"2","field_name3":"3","field_name3":"1000"...
```

problem I have is that the form has multiple input types , textarea , select , radio
and I need to figure out what they are based on the object key , look for name and return type , so I could do something like if radio set checked checked and so on

I tried

```
Object.each(dafaultValues, function(value, key){
 var filed_name = MyForm.elements[''+key+''];
 console.log(filed_name.type);

});
```

problem with this is that radio type have same name but different id's

```
<input type="radio" name="field_name5" id="field_name51" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="field_name5" id="field_name52" value="1" checked="checked">
```

and I endup  with js error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

so what would be the best way to find out what the input type is before I can do

```
if(field.type ='radio'){

//set checked checked..
}
```

Comment: You don't need a complex function. Every `form` element natively has a [`reset` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.reset)

Comment: like advised above it is Ajax form , not normal form submiion where I have default values , once form is submited defaults change. I dont need reset only while the user is there but I need it also when he comes back thus I have the default values stored in a variable

Comment: That doesn't matter, just set the default values as you do in the beginning when you receive the values from ajax.

Comment: Take a look at this example. I just put it together very dirty, but you will get the idea ;) http://jsfiddle.net/uqN7d/

Comment: I will post it as an answer. So you can complete this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example. I just put it together very dirty, but you will get the idea ;)

HTML:

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="2"/>
    <input type="radio" name="abc" value="3"/>
    <input type="text" name="def" value="change" />
</form>​
```

JS:

```
var values = {
    'abc': '2',
    'def': 'original'
};
var els = $('test').getElements('[name="abc"], input');
els.each(function(el) {
    var defaultVal = values[el.get('name')],
        type = el.get('type');

    if (typeof defaultVal != 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    if (type == "radio") {
        if (el.get('value') == defaultVal) {
            el.set('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
            el.erase('checked');
        }
    }

   if (type == "text") {
       el.set('value', defaultVal);
   }
});
```

Comment: edited to make less fragile for when values[name] is falsy (eg. 0).

Comment: nice one for undefined check , that is what was giving me trouble the most. thank you!